# How can show has_many :through Association with ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I have many to many relation between `projects` and `project_category` through `project_by_category`.
My models:

`Project Model`

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  # Relationships
  has_many :project_by_categories
  has_many :project_categories, through: :project_by_categories
```

`ProjectCategory Model`

```
class ProjectCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_by_categories
  has_many :projects, through: :project_by_categories
```

`ProjectByCategory Model`

```
class ProjectByCategory < ApplicationRecord
  # Relationships
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :project_category
```

My serializers:

`Project Serializer`

```
class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :image, :name, :description
```

`Project Category Serializer`

```
  class ProjectCategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer              
    attributes :id, :name

    has_many :projects
```

`The expected result:`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "project-categories",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "3D design basics"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "projects": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                             "image": "",
                             "name": "",
                             "description": "", 
                            "type": "projects"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                             "image": "",
                             "name": "",
                             "description": "", 
                            "type": "projects"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

`But this is the result:`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "project-categories",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "3D design basics"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "projects": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "type": "projects"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "type": "projects"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

In the project relationship only show me the id and the type.

`By last this is my controller`

```
class Api::V1::CategoriesController < ApiController
    def index
        @categories = ProjectCategory.all
        render json: @categories
    end
```

Thank you for your answers!!

Answer (score 0):

Your joins table appears to be setup correctly (and you seem to be grabbing the expected objects from your database), but you are just missing the additional serialized attributes.

Have you tried passing the `serializer:` or `each_serializer:` arguments to the respective serializer and controller? For example, your `Api::V1::CategoriesController` might look like this:

```
class Api::V1::CategoriesController < ApiController
  def index
    @categories = ProjectCategory.all
    render json: @categories, each_serializer: ProjectCategorySerializer
  end
end
```

Similarly, your `ProjectCategorySerializer` would contain:

```
class ProjectCategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name

  has_many :projects, each_serializer: ProjectSerializer
```

I'm not sure if ActiveModel::Serializers are now a part of ActiveSupport, but [the library](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#status) seems to suggest that development has tapered off. I'd recommend switching a a different library if possible.

Hope this helps!